# Displaying SELECT field on custom post type archive page using TIMBER

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type, event, that has a SELECT field that grabs the Post Object of another custom post type, listing. So we have an event and we want to select a business listing that it's attached to it so we can display the business's contact information (phone, address, etc).

functions.php

```
function register_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'swfl_listing', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'          => __( 'Listings' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Listing' )
        ),
        'rewrite'         => array(
            'slug'       => 'destinations/listings',
        ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'revisions', 'author', 'comments' ),
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-businessman',
    ) );

    register_post_type( 'swfl_event', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'          => 'Events',
            'singular_name' => 'Event',
        ),
        'rewrite'         => array(
            'slug'       => 'discover/events',
        ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'revisions', 'comments' ),
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
    ) );
}

function add_to_context( $context ) {
    ...
    $context['events'] = Timber::get_posts( array(
        'post_type'      => 'swfl_event',
    ) );
    ...
}
```

I searched and found this line of code that allows me to grab the information on the Singular page `listing_sponsoring_event` being the custom field.

single.php & archive.php

```
...
$context['listing'] = new TimberPost( $post->listing_sponsoring_event );
...
```

Here is working code on the singular page

single-swfl_event.twig

```
...
<strong>Where: </strong> {{ listing.title }} <br/>
<strong>Price: </strong> {{ post.get_field('event_price') }} <br/>
...
```

But the same code does not work if I put it into archive.php. It just shows the last post information in the loop.

archive-swfl_event.twig

```
...
{% for post in posts %}
    ...
    <strong>Where: </strong> {{ listing.title }} <br/>
    <strong>Price: </strong> {{ post.get_field('event_price') }} <br/>
    ...
{% endfor %}
...
```

---

***Edit:*** I haven't been able to figure out anything using Timber/Twig (nor a response), but I'm leaving this question open just in case it gets figured out eventually. For now I am using a function with PHP to grab the information. It's not a pretty solution.

Hopefully Timber will eventually be updated to support SELECT and WP Post objects more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my problem was really just with working with WP Post Objects and how to get it's information. For any of you who also have problems:

Instead of `{{ post.custom_field_name }}`, access the object information with `{{ post.get_field('custom_field_name') }}`. `{{ post.custom_field_name }}` only gives me the ID of the Object.

For troubleshooting,  call 
`{{ post.get_field('custom_field_name')|print_r }}` for a list of data you can retrieve.

Now I can grab the data I want with `{{ post.get_field('custom_field_name').post_title }}`.